# preprocessing for tensorflow rnn with groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I am currently following the training https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series
However, I am wondering how to modify the code to a dataset with multiple group_id and the timeseries should be only be generated based on the same group_id

Below is the current code based on the tutorial i am following with my edit under make_dataset.

I was wondering if there is a better way for doing this as the make dataset is too long on my actual dataset

```
#Create dummy df
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df["group_id"] = pd.Series(['A']*25+ ['B']*20+['C']*20 + ['D']*35)
for id in df.group_id.unique():
    df.loc[df.group_id==id,'timestamp']=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018',periods=df[df.group_id==id].shape[0])
df=df.set_index(['group_id','timestamp'])
df['cumcount']=df.groupby('group_id').cumcount()
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col]/100+df.cumcount/10
df=df.drop(['cumcount'],axis=1)

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython
import IPython.display
column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(df.columns)}

n = len(df)
train_df = df[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df[int(n*0.9):]

num_features = df.shape[1]
class WindowGenerator():
  def __init__(self, input_width, label_width, shift,
               train_df=train_df, val_df=val_df, test_df=test_df,
               label_columns=None):
    # Store the raw data.
    self.train_df = train_df
    self.val_df = val_df
    self.test_df = test_df

    # Work out the label column indices.
    self.label_columns = label_columns
    if label_columns is not None:
      self.label_columns_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                                    enumerate(label_columns)}
    self.column_indices = {name: i for i, name in
                           enumerate(train_df.columns)}

    # Work out the window parameters.
    self.input_width = input_width
    self.label_width = label_width
    self.shift = shift

    self.total_window_size = input_width + shift

    self.input_slice = slice(0, input_width)
    self.input_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.input_slice]

    self.label_start = self.total_window_size - self.label_width
    self.labels_slice = slice(self.label_start, None)
    self.label_indices = np.arange(self.total_window_size)[self.labels_slice]

  def __repr__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        f'Total window size: {self.total_window_size}',
        f'Input indices: {self.input_indices}',
        f'Label indices: {self.label_indices}',
        f'Label column name(s): {self.label_columns}'])

def plot(self, model=None, plot_col='A', max_subplots=3):
  inputs, labels = self.example
  plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
  plot_col_index = self.column_indices[plot_col]
  max_n = min(max_subplots, len(inputs))
  for n in range(max_n):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, n+1)
    plt.ylabel(f'{plot_col} [normed]')
    plt.plot(self.input_indices, inputs[n, :, plot_col_index],
             label='Inputs', marker='.', zorder=-10)

    if self.label_columns:
      label_col_index = self.label_columns_indices.get(plot_col, None)
    else:
      label_col_index = plot_col_index

    if label_col_index is None:
      continue

    plt.scatter(self.label_indices, labels[n, :, label_col_index],
                edgecolors='k', label='Labels', c='#2ca02c', s=64)
    if model is not None:
      predictions = model(inputs)
      plt.scatter(self.label_indices, predictions[n, :, label_col_index],
                  marker='X', edgecolors='k', label='Predictions',
                  c='#ff7f0e', s=64)

    if n == 0:
      plt.legend()

  plt.xlabel('Time [h]')

WindowGenerator.plot=plot
def split_window(self, features):
  inputs = features[:, self.input_slice, :]
  labels = features[:, self.labels_slice, :]
  if self.label_columns is not None:
    labels = tf.stack(
        [labels[:, :, self.column_indices[name]] for name in self.label_columns],
        axis=-1)

  # Slicing doesn't preserve static shape information, so set the shapes
  # manually. This way the `tf.data.Datasets` are easier to inspect.
  inputs.set_shape([None, self.input_width, None])
  labels.set_shape([None, self.label_width, None])

  return inputs, labels

WindowGenerator.split_window = split_window
```

I only specifically made changes to this section in order to address the group.

```
def process_dataset(self,data):
    
  data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
  ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
      data=data,
      targets=None,
      sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
      sequence_stride=1,
      shuffle=True,
      batch_size=32,)

  ds = ds.map(self.split_window)
  return ds
def make_dataset(self,data):
    dataset=data.groupby('group_id').apply(lambda x:self.process_dataset(x))
    ds=dataset[0]


    for i in range(1,data.index.get_level_values(0).nunique()):
        ds=ds.concatenate(dataset[i])
    return ds

WindowGenerator.make_dataset = make_dataset
```

Code below as per tutorial

```
@property
def train(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)

@property
def val(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)

@property
def test(self):
  return self.make_dataset(self.test_df)

@property
def example(self):
  """Get and cache an example batch of `inputs, labels` for plotting."""
  result = getattr(self, '_example', None)
  if result is None:
    # No example batch was found, so get one from the `.train` dataset
    result = next(iter(self.train))
    # And cache it for next time
    self._example = result
  return result

WindowGenerator.train = train
WindowGenerator.val = val
WindowGenerator.test = test
WindowGenerator.example = example

MAX_EPOCHS = 2000

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=20):
  early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

  model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

  history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping])
  return history

OUT_STEPS = 10
multi_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=10,
                               label_width=OUT_STEPS,
                               shift=OUT_STEPS)

multi_window
multi_lstm_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Shape [batch, time, features] => [batch, lstm_units]
    # Adding more `lstm_units` just overfits more quickly.
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False),
    # Shape => [batch, out_steps*features]
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(OUT_STEPS*num_features,
                          kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.zeros),
    # Shape => [batch, out_steps, features]
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape([OUT_STEPS, num_features])
])

history = compile_and_fit(multi_lstm_model, multi_window)

IPython.display.clear_output()
multi_window.plot(multi_lstm_model,plot_col='B',max_subplots=3)
```